# How to make the width of the cell element be the same as the longer caption?

Tags: css, firefox, caption

What should I add to the code below, so that the red and blue rectangles are the same width?

the result obtained (under Firefox)
[image]

the result I would like:
[image]

I searched for the solution for a long time in this link
https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#table
but I haven't found how to do it

**edit : I don't want line-break in the caption**

```css
caption {
  width:fit-content; /* I keep this line!*/
  border: 1px solid blue
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    the caption zone the caption zone the caption...
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td>the td the td </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Firefox renders the example exactly the same as Chrome for me - when `width:fit-content;` gets removed.

Comment: If you can remove the extra line breaks around the caption text in the HTML, then maybe use `white-space: pre`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the width:fit-content; from caption css.
Then you will have the same behavior in both chrome and firefox.

Edited*

To make this wireframe in chrome you have to add this line to caption tag:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

About firefox, the only way i can think of is with js

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.width = document.getElementsByTagName('caption')[0].clientWidth + 'px'
```

You can use id or classes and foreach instead of tags, of course.

Comment: I don't want line-break in the caption element (I just added this clarification in my question)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what result you expect. Can you add some wireframe?